# How to remove size property from input generated by text_field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I have an .erb file with form template that uses `form_for` helper to generate form, and some of their fields generated with `text_field` method. In resulting HTML I see `size` properties are added to every input generated with aforementioned method.

I want to control input sizes with CSS and that `size` property prevents me from doing it. Is there any way to tell `text_field` method that I don't want them?

I tried to pass `:size => nil` as option to that method, but that didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS or the :size option to control the size of input fields.  I'm not sure if there is an option to remove the size attribute, I've always just ignored it and set the width of input fields with CSS.

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me

```
<%= f.text_field :title, :size => nil %>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<%= f.text_field :name, :size => nil, :style => "width: 120px; height: 20px;" %>`. This will work